# Writing to the same file from multiple threads . Synchronization? locking ? [Pthreads] [ PHP]

Tags: php, multithreading

Basic question about mutltithreading with pthreads..
N number of threads all writing to the same file at different/similar/same times .. How do I make it 'safe' ? i.e make sure no 2 threads try to write at the same time.

```
  class WebRequest extends Thread {
      public $cik;

      public function __construct($cik){
          $this->cik = $cik;
      }

      public function run() {
          for_cik($this->cik);
          echo 'Running Thread : ' . $this->getCurrentThreadId() ."\n";
          sleep(rand(1,3)) ;
      }

      function for_cik($cik) {
          //doing work

          // lock() ; ?
          Log_NIK::getInstance()->write_line($log) ; //write this 'safely'
          //unlock() ; ?
      }
  }
```

I searched, but found only language specific advise (for other languages . C# / java etc)

Edit:

the write_line function is :

```
    function write_line($line){

        file_put_contents($this->logFileName,$line."\n",FILE_APPEND) ;
    }
```

Comment: Probably because you didn't show all of your code. Where is the code for: Log_NIK::getInstance()->write_line(). So we can see how your writing the file.. You can't just dump a mess of code and expect us to figure it out. Take the time to write a good question, as clearly as possible, with as much detail as we will need so we can see what is going on..

Answer (score 4):

You don't show all of your code. If your using file_put_contents() somewhere, you would pass the LOCK_EX flag.

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', 'content', LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: That's it? all it needs is the LOCK_EX flag ?

Comment: It locks the file so nothing else can access it until it's done. The other threads would wait until it's unlocked.

Answer (score -1):

In the beginning search for the existing of a particular file. If not present - create it and then discard it in the end. If another thread is trying to write in it, it won't be able to do so.

```
$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "somefile.txt", "w+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) { 
    // do your stuff here

    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // release the lock
    unlink (dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "somefile.txt");
}

fclose($fp);
```